# How to map LINQ EntitySet to List property in property setter?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

In my model I have these entities:

```
public interface IOrder
{
   string Name {get;set;}
   List<IProduct> OrderedProducts {get;set;}
}

public interface IProduct {}
```

In partial class generated by linq-to-sql I map these properties on my entity properties:

```
public partial class Order : IOrder
{
   List<IProduct> OrderedProducts
   {
      get { return this.L2SQLProducts.Cast<IProduct>.ToList(); }
      set { this.L2SQLProducts = ??? }
   }
}
```

How should setter look like?

EDIT: Purpose of this is to have interface that I could MOCK for unit testing or change linq-to-sql to another DAL.

Comment: What is the name and type of the property in the `Order` class?

Answer (score 2):

汗了。。。
这样不怕性能问题吗？
如果我这样编码呢？

```
var a = xx.OrderedProducts[0];
var b = xx.OrderedProducts[1];
```

这样不是要该问了两次数据库吗？

translate to english:
what?
this can be slowly when run.

if I code like this:

```
var a = xx.OrderedProducts[0];
var b = xx.OrderedProducts[1];
```

Is that you will access to the database twice?

Answer (score 1):

An EntitySet implements IList so rather than dealing with a derived List instance, why not use the interface IList and simply assign it directly, as in:

```
public interface IOrder
{
   string Name {get;set;}
   IList<IProduct> OrderedProducts {get;set;}
}
```

Alternatively, you could instantiate an entity set, and copy over the objects in the list to that entity set.  There may be alternative consequences to this.

```
   List<IProduct> OrderedProducts
   {
      get { return this.L2SQLProducts.Cast<IProduct>.ToList(); }
      set { 
           this.L2SQLProducts = new EntitySet<IProduct>();
           foreach (var entry in value)
              this.L2SQLProducts.Add(entry);
      }
   }
```

HTH.